# objective c loop blocking user input while video recording with AvFoundation?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hello every time i try to record the date with CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); my app ignores the rest of the buttons, it's as if it takes over all memory and blocks all user input. I was wondering what i am doing wrong? I thought of making a function showtime() but i dont know how to pass values between functions from toggleRecording to showtime  so that my method would work if this would even solve the problem. Below is my code:

```
- (IBAction)toggleRecording:(id)sender
{
    // Start recording if there isn't a recording running. Stop recording if there is.
    [[self recordButton] setEnabled:NO];
    if (![[[self captureManager] recorder] isRecording]){
        [[self captureManager] startRecording];

        /* figure out a day to record for every half a second
         while([[[self captureManager]recorder] isRecording]){
         CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
         NSLog(@" time is %i", startTime);
         }

        */
    }
    else
        [[self captureManager] stopRecording];


}

-(void)showtime:(id)sender{
    while([[[self captureManager]recorder] isRecording]){
        CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        NSLog(@" time is %f", startTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application has to run the event loop to receive the events. While your own code is doing something else (here it's doing a "while" loop), events are queued and not delivered until your code returns.

Schematically, an application is doing something like:

```
while(1) {
    event = _UIReceiveNextQueuedEvent();
    _UIProcessEvent(event); // <- this calls -showTime:
}
```

If you want to record time while not blocking the loop, you will have to schedule an `NSTimer` every 0.5s and invalidate it as soon as recording is turned off.

Something like:

```
- (void)showTime:(id)sender
{
    if ([[[self captureManager]recorder] isRecording]) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if ([[[self captureManager]recorder] isRecording]) {
        CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        NSLog(@" time is %f", startTime);
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i call these methods? viewfinishedloading? or will they execute automatically. sorry just started coding a couple of days ago on ios again after 2 years.

Comment: `-showTime:` is called as before. `-timerFired:` is automatically called every 0.5s by the timer.